# Why firebug console is not showing any thing or not sowing any log

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, console

I am executing the code below. I am getting the Result in the view but getting no http request information in the console tab of Firebug.

```
$.ajax({
       // url: url+'merge_code/gatTabContentByTabId',  secured http issue
        url: 'http://localhost/crm_v2/merge_code/gatTabContentByTabId',
        //async: false,
        type: "POST",
        data: {tab_id:tab_id},
        cache: false,
        dataType: "text",
        success:function(responce, textStatus, jqXHR){
        console.log(responce);

                $("table.content_table").html("");
                $("table.content_table").html(responce);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert(textStatus);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Right click in console and tick "Log Request and Response Bodies".

Comment: Or you might have selected some particular tab like `error`, `warning`. Check if you have `all` tab selected?

Comment: Sorry , there is no option like "Log Request and Response Bodies" on console right click.

Comment: Some times before it was not working for the same option. But now its working by ticking on "Show XMLHttpRequests"  option from right click of console tab. Why it happen like this ?